# How can I ask for a web server to serve their "mobile friendly" version of their web pages with eww?

Tags: eww

I'm using `eww` lately for browsing the web looking for documentation and things like that. I dislike that `eww` receives the same web page as it were Firefox or Google Chrome, it cannot render web pages as those web browsers do. Then, what I want to achieve is to make `eww` tell the web sites that it visits that send the *mobile friendly* version of their web pages, thus, I would have a simpler layout rendered by `eww` (or at least that's my assumption).

Comment: Never used eww, but the trick could be to fake your User-Agent. Most of the time the webserver check that value before redirecting you to the mobile version of the website.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`eww` uses the `url` library, so we can add advice to `url-http-user-agent-string` to fake the `User-Agent` string:

```
(advice-add 'url-http-user-agent-string :around
            (lambda (ignored)
              "Pretend to be a mobile browser."
              (concat
               "User-Agent: "
               "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30")))
```

I took a mobile browser User-Agent string from [`www.useragentstring.com`](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/).

With this advice I get the mobile version of `google.com`; your mileage may vary.

(I found this by using `M-x apropos RET user-agent RET`.)

Comment: You might want to check that current major mode is `eww` before changing the user-agent changing it unconditionally **might** break other packages depending on url library

Comment: what about `emacs-w3m`? how to get mobile version? As I know, these days we are actually use responsive design, so the point is fake screen size instead agent string.

Comment: changing user-agent is something required because some web servers will serve a page lacking of Javascript, something which isn't evaluated by eww anyway...

Comment: @IqbalAnsari: Unfortunately `eww` calls `url-http-user-agent-string` with the current buffer in `fundamental-mode` (a buffer returned by `process-buffer`), so this does not work. I agree that it would be much better to set the user agent string **for `eww` only**, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: @chenbin: You need to set `w3m-user-agent`. See [this post by Sacha Chua](http://sachachua.com/blog/2008/08/emacs-and-w3m-fake-your-user-agent/) for one way to do it.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work in latest emacs, it prevents pages from ever loading

Comment: figured it out, at the end of the user agent string you need to add "\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Emacs, you can simply use the customization variable `url-user-agent`:

```
(setq url-user-agent "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7\n")
```

Comment: Sorry, how recent?

Comment: It was introduced on Nov 5, 2014.